# Place arrow image on bottom border

Tags: css

Following is my jsfiddle in which I am trying to place an arrow image on the bottom border centerally aligned but I am unable to do that. Kindly let me know how to put an arrow image so its centrally aligned no matter what the width of the box is or height? Thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/wn7JN/463/

```
.bubble 
{
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border: #000 solid 1px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.arrow:before 
{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 26px 26px 0;
    border-color: #000 transparent;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    background-image:url(http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20120818025551/merlin1/images/4/46/Drop_down_arrow.gif);
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Comment: @Harry no not like this because when I changed the width the arrow doesn't remain centrally aligned plus there is a black icon arrow. I am trying to only use the image behind it and only one arrow. Currently the tiled arrows are appearing

Comment: @Harry ummmm I have to use image. Its kind of requirement but thanks for the tip and I found great site for that http://cssarrowplease.com/

Comment: I have removed my comments because JeyTheva's comment update seems to be what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. I add some changes check,

```
.bubble 
{
position: relative;
width: 600px;
height: 50px;
padding: 0px;
background: #FFFFFF;
border: #000 solid 1px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
}

.arrow:before 
{
content: "";
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
    bottom:-26px;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 26px 26px 0;
border-color: #000 transparent;
display: block;
width: 0;
z-index: 0;
    margin:0 0 0 -26px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am trying to only use the image behind it and only one arrow. Currently the tiled arrows are appearing. Plus I am also trying to get rid of that BLACK CSS ARROW.

Comment: yes only single image arrow, centrally aligned on bottom border

Comment: top of the border bottom or bottom of the border bottom??

Comment: Its Perfect, working fine on my lis too, Thanks alot!!

Answer (score 0):

replace the .arrow:before style & try it. it will align the arrow at center bottom.

```
.arrow:before 
{
content: "";
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top:100%;
margin-left:-26px;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 26px 26px 0;
border-color: #000 transparent;
display: block;
width: 0;
background:url(http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20120818025551/merlin1/images/4/46/Drop_down_arrow.gif);
z-index: 0;
}
```

Comment: it shows ther arrow after the border of of dive.. if you want to see inside the div then just replace top:100% with bottom:0; hope you will have the good result